# RSS image into my AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, rss

I'm trying to pull the hero images for a new blog published each time and use RSS to create the content in the email. At this time all the content gets pulled in instead of the image. Can you please help what I should do it get this result. Any help will be appreciated. My code is below.

Thank you!

```
    <div padding:="" 15px="" 15px;="">

%%[

var @xml, @isXML, @nodes, @rowCount @i, @maxToDisplay,
Set @xml = HTTPGet("https://feeds.feedburner.com/Sonar", false, 0, @CallStatus)


if indexOf(@xml,"<channel>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/rss/channel/item",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)
  

 

  if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to 1 do

   
      var @title
      var @description
      var @link
      var @Image



      set @nodepath = concat("/rss/channel/item[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"))) > 0 then
          set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"))) > 0 then
          set @description = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"))) > 0 then
          set @link = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"),0),1),'Value')
      endif
      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[",@i,"]/image"),0)) > 0 then
      set @image = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[",@i,"]/image"),0),1),'Value')
    endif
      
 
      ]%%


       <h4>%%=v(@title)=%%</h4>
<br>
 <img src="%%=v(@Image)=%%">

       %%=v(@description)=%%
         <br> 
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>         
<div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="%%=redirectto(@link)=%%" style="height:53px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="8%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#c72b28">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="%%=redirectto(@link)=%%" style="background-color:#c72b28;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;line-height:53px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:150px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Read Now</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
                </center><table class="button" width="30%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    
                        <tr>
                 
     </tr>
                
    </table></td></tr></table>
  

<br>
 %%[

    next @i

  else

   outputline(concat("<br>no items found"))

  endif

else

  outputline(concat("<br>no XML found"))

endif

]%%


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [indenting](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html), reviewing the XML in [your feed](https://feeds.feedburner.com/Sonar) (view the source), and then [testing your XPaths](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) before even attempting to write the AMPscript to parse it.

Looks like the images are part of the `content:encoded` nodes:

[image]

Once you get the value of that node for each item, you'll need to parse out the *img* tag with the AMPscript string functions ([indexOf](https://ampscript.guide/indexOf), [substring](https://ampscript.guide/substring), and maybe as a last resort, [regexmatch](https://ampscript.guide/regexmatch)).

Comment: Super new to AMP script. So this seems very high-level to me. Can you explain this in a simpler manner what exactly do I need to focus on?

Comment: Parsing RSS XML is an advanced AMPscript topic, in my opinion, which is why I suggested focusing on understanding the anatomy of RSS XML and XPATH.  Both of those are foundational to understanding the [buildrowsetfromxml](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromxml) AMPscript function.